# Navigate back to an existing activity with MvxViewModel.ShowViewModel<> and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using Xamarin and MvvmCross to create an Android app.
I'm trying to navigate BACK from my child ViewModel (view, activity, whatever) to my parent ViewModel. Lets say I have backstack A->B->C and I'm trying to navigate from C to A having C and B destroyed and A reactivated.

Here I can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and navigation using Intent class:

```
var startActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainView));
startActivityIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
StartActivity(startActivityIntent);
```

and it works fine (except of the fact that my parent activity A is destroyed and created new instead of restarted.

But I need navigation logic to be in my ViewModel (core library, shared across all platforms).

What is the correct way to navigate back to existing activity from PCL (using MvxViewModel.ShowViewMode() method)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a `ViewModel` you can simply use `Close(this)`.

Comment: in this case activity A is re-created and my back stack is: A->A

Comment: It really depends on what your presenter does.

Comment: I don't use custom presenter. Everything is from default + monodroid + xamarin + mvvmcross application.

Answer (score 0):

Have the `[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]` attribute on the activity class A